# UITextField return key text change from "Done" to "Post"

Tags: iphone

I have created a sample application that has the `textField` and its return key type should be done. I want to change text from "Done" to "Post".

I really need do it.

Please help me ?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

now apple only support these type:

```
typedef enum {
   UIReturnKeyDefault,//Set the text of the return key to “return”.
   UIReturnKeyGo,//Set the text of the return key to “Go”.
   UIReturnKeyGoogle,//Set the text of the return key to “Google”.
   UIReturnKeyJoin,//Set the text of the return key to “Join”.
   UIReturnKeyNext,//Set the text of the return key to “Next”.
   UIReturnKeyRoute,//Set the text of the return key to “Route”.
   UIReturnKeySearch,//Set the text of the return key to “Search”.
   UIReturnKeySend,//Set the text of the return key to “Send”.
   UIReturnKeyYahoo,//Set the text of the return key to “Yahoo”.
   UIReturnKeyDone,//Set the text of the return key to “Done”.
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,//Set the text of the return key to “Emergency Call”.
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

Maybe you can use send instead.

Answer (score 2):

You get the return key and keyboard types defined in the OS. Unless you want to try to hack the keyboard's view hierarchy to change that button, which would be a really bad plan. (Standard recommendation here is to file a bug report with Apple to let them know you'd like more/different options.

Comment: ok.If i can add subview of uibutton in uikeyboard has referred here.http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key.. Then apple can reject my application ?